# Queueing of slots in QT

Tags: c++, qt

Couldn't seem to find an answer in the documentation, however I'm not entirely sure I was looking in the right places. I have a signal connected to a slot, for example with my QIODevice `connect(port, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(handleReadyRead()));` If the signal `readyRead()` is emitted twice in quick succession, say before the slot has finished processing, will the slot be called concurrently or queued and run one after the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never by itself invoke slots in a new thread. However if you already have multiple threads, slots can be executed in parallel. When exactly the slot will be invoked depends on the connection type, which you can specify in the connect call.

A QObject *lives in* a thread. By default in the one it was created, but you can move objects between threads.

Default connection type works like that:

- If the receiver lives in the same thread, slot will be invoked immediately in the same thread.
- Otherwise slot will be invoked when the thread of the receiver returns to the event loop. It is executed in the thread of the receiver.

More info here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum